# Having trouble using the 'gather' function in tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, tidyr

I am having trouble using the gather function in R.
This is the sample data frame -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF = data.frame(Region = c("Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Europe", "Europe"),
                `Indicator Name` = c("Population", "GDP", "GNI", "Population", "GDP"),
                `2004` = c(22, 33,44,55,56),
                `2005` =c(223, 44,555,66,64))

Region Indicator.Name X2004 X2005
1   Asia     Population    22   223
2   Asia            GDP    33    44
3   Asia            GNI    44   555
4 Europe     Population    55    66
5 Europe            GDP    56    64
```

And this is the data frame that I want

```
DF2 = data.frame(Region = c("Asia", "Asia", "Europe", "Europe"),
                 Year =  c("X2004", "X2005"),
                 population = c(22, 224, 55, 66),
                 GDP = c(33, 44, 56,64))

Region  Year population GDP
1   Asia X2004         22  33
2   Asia X2005        224  44
3 Europe X2004         55  56
4 Europe X2005         66  64
```

I want to do this via the `gather` function in `tidyr`.
I am not sure how to go about this. This is what I tried -

```
gather(DF, key= DF$Indicator.Name, values = "values")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `gather` and `spread`, you have:

```r
DF %>% 
  gather(-Indicator.Name, -Region, key= "Year", value = "value") %>%
  spread(Indicator.Name, value)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not a simple `gather` function.  First you need to make the dataframe long and then make it wide switching the desired columns.
Here is a solution using the new `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF = data.frame(Region = c("Asia", "Asia", "Asia", "Europe", "Europe"),
                `Indicator Name` = c("Population", "GDP", "GNI", "Population", "GDP"),
                `2004` = c(22, 33,44,55,56),
                `2005` =c(223, 44,555,66,64))



DF %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("x")) %>% 
       pivot_wider(names_from = Indicator.Name, values_from = value) 

# A tibble: 4 x 5
Region name  Population   GDP   GNI
<fct>  <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Asia   X2004         22    33    44
2 Asia   X2005        223    44   555
3 Europe X2004         55    56    NA
4 Europe X2005         66    64    NA
```

Comment: I would have loved to use the pivot_longer function but they haven't released  it on the CRAN update of tidyr. Having trouble installing it from devtools - will just have to wait till it releases on CRAN.

Comment: `pivot_longer` is part of tidyr 1.0.0 released on CRAN on Sept 1, 2019.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/index.html